# Unable to read Props in React JS Hook

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I am new to React JS and I have a piece of code ES6 code with React Hooks. I am trying to access the props element that was sent from a Parent but I cant read it here. I can read it with the class based React App but not the Hooks implementation.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

//Packages
import axios from 'axios';
import BootstrapTable from 'react-bootstrap-table-next';
import paginationFactory from 'react-bootstrap-table2-paginator';
import * as ReactBootStrap from 'react-bootstrap';

const DisplayTable = () => {
  const [players, setPlayers] = useState([]);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);


  const getPlayerData = async () => {
    const data = this.props.jsondata  //This line of code!
  };


  const columns = [
    { dataField: "name", text:"name" },
    { dataField: "points_per_game", text:"points_per_game" },
    { dataField: "team_name", text:"team_name" },
  ]

  useEffect(()=> {
    getPlayerData();
  }, []);

  return(
  <div>
    <BootstrapTable
      keyField="name"
      data={players}
      columns={columns}
      pagination={paginationFactory()}
    />

  </div>
  )
};

export default DisplayTable;
```

Comment: There is no such thing as `this` in a functional component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to read the props from the `this` context for functional components.

The functional component takes the `props` as a parameter:

```
const DisplayTable = (props) => {
  const [players, setPlayers] = useState([]);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);


  const getPlayerData = async () => {
    const data = props.jsondata  //This line of code!
  };
  ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks a ton. It worked. But not the way I wanted to.
In the parent component, I am uploading a json file and as soon as click a button I am supposed to render the child component. Currently what is happening is that the child component is just called once. During the reload of page. How do I do it so that everytime I click the Button the child component should be re-rendered.
```
<div>
<button onClick={this.importCSVToJSON}>View now</button>
</div>
//My Function parses the CSV and this is when I want to render the below
<div>
<DisplayTable csvdata = {this.state.csvdata}/>
</div>
```